# Cassandra compile issue about lambda

Tags: java, lambda, cassandra, java-8

The Cassandra source code is up-to-date, which is cloned from git@github.com:apache/cassandra.git.

JDK version is 1.8.0_05

OS: Linux 3.13.0-62-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP

```
[javac] **/cassandra/test/burn/org/apache/cassandra/utils/LongBTreeTest.java:83: error: reference to testRandomSelection is ambiguous
[javac]         testRandomSelection(perThreadTrees, perTreeSelections,
[javac]         ^
[javac]   both method testRandomSelection(int,int,BTreeTestFactory) in LongBTreeTest and method testRandomSelection(int,int,Consumer<RandomSelection>) in LongBTreeTest match
[javac] **/cassandra/test/burn/org/apache/cassandra/utils/LongBTreeTest.java:157: error: reference to testRandomSelection is ambiguous
[javac]         testRandomSelection(perThreadTrees, 4,
[javac]         ^
[javac]   both method testRandomSelection(int,int,BTreeTestFactory) in LongBTreeTest and method testRandomSelection(int,int,Consumer<RandomSelection>) in LongBTreeTest match
[javac] **/cassandra/test/burn/org/apache/cassandra/utils/LongBTreeTest.java:158: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
[javac]                             (selection) ->
[javac]                             ^
[javac]     missing return value
[javac] **/cassandra/test/burn/org/apache/cassandra/utils/LongBTreeTest.java:269: error: reference to testRandomSelection is ambiguous
[javac]         testRandomSelection(perThreadTrees, perTreeSelections, (selection) -> {
[javac]         ^
[javac]   both method testRandomSelection(int,int,BTreeTestFactory) in LongBTreeTest and method testRandomSelection(int,int,Consumer<RandomSelection>) in LongBTreeTest match
[javac] **/cassandra/test/burn/org/apache/cassandra/utils/LongBTreeTest.java:269: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
[javac]         testRandomSelection(perThreadTrees, perTreeSelections, (selection) -> {
[javac]                                                                ^
[javac]     missing return value
```

Later, I tried to compile it using different JDK versions, found that jdk1.8.0_11 still had the same issue, but starting with jdk1.8.0_20, this issue is fixed.

I want to ask what causes this issue. Can anyone tell me the bug id from JDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the [JDK-8029718](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029718) bug which was actually fixed in 1.8.0_20. In general many bugs were fixed in 1.8.0_20 and 1.8.0_40 in javac compiler related to lambda type inference. It's recommended to use the latest compiler version.

Comment: agree, it's the answer which I expected. Thanks